# how to route traffic from one host to another with hops in between

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking, nat

I have a VM (HOST A) on a Hypervisor in a network that cannot see the outside world.  I have another VM (HOST B) on another Hypervisor that can see the outside world.  I can ping HOST B from HOST A.  I want to route traffic from HOST A to HOST B so I can reach the outside.

HOST A example IP: 172.17.175.5

HOST B example IP: 10.130.128.242

On HOST B I have done

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ethx -j MASQUERADE
```

on HOST A I tried doing

```
ip route del default  
ip route add default via IP_of_HOSTA
```

but I get RTNETLINK answers network is unreachable

run traceroute on HOST A for 10.130.128.242 shows

```
 1  172.17.175.1 (172.17.175.1)  0.453 ms  0.877 ms  0.870 ms
 2  172.16.1.1 (172.16.1.1)  0.861 ms  0.853 ms  0.844 ms
 3  la.la.la.net (172.16.255.254)  2.567 ms  2.627 ms  4.439 ms
 4  10.0.40.105 (10.0.40.105)  1.921 ms  2.122 ms  2.253 ms
 5  10.250.247.4 (10.250.247.4)  1.465 ms  1.495 ms  1.765 ms
 6  blah.blah.blah.net (10.130.128.242)  0.811 ms  0.787 ms  2.412 ms
```

is it possible to do this with only editing configs on the two VMs? If so how?

the VMs are set up in bridge mode if that matters.

UPDATE: 
after adding

```
ip route add 10.130.128.242/32 via 172.17.120.1
```

ip route shows

```
10.130.128.242 via 172.17.120.1 dev ens3
172.17.120.0/26 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.120.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a route to Host B via the original default gateway on Host A.

`ip route add IPOFHOSTB/32 via original_gateway`

Only then change the default.

Comment: thanks, but I am still getting a "RTNETLINK answers Network is unreachable" when I try to add it as default.  I updated my question with what my route table looks like now

Comment: Do you get that when pinging the gateway or something else? From the route table, you seem to have forgotten to add the default route after adding a route to the default gateway which is in another network.